# Socket is not connected in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, websocket, socket.io

I tried to connect the server using a socket but it refuses to connect. Here I am trying to send the query parameter(token) with the base URL to connect the server. But still, it's not connecting.

Here is console output error:

```
manager  <SocketIO.SocketManager: 0x283542f00>
2020-01-23 17:59:12.872248+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736351] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting, 2]
2020-01-23 17:59:12.872415+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736351] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Joining namespace /
2020-01-23 17:59:12.872543+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736351] LOG SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting
2020-01-23 17:59:12.872621+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736351] LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
2020-01-23 17:59:12.873836+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736455] LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: https://base url/event-stream/
2020-01-23 17:59:12.874735+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736455] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
2020-01-23 17:59:13.452879+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736457] ERROR SocketEngine: Invalid HTTP upgrade. code=404, type=upgradeError
2020-01-23 17:59:13.455416+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736351] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: websocketUpgrade with data: [["server": "nginx/1.17.4", "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload", "content-length": "153", "vary": "Accept-Encoding", "content-type": "text/html", "connection": "keep-alive", "date": "Thu, 23 Jan 2020 12"]]
2020-01-23 17:59:13.455832+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736351] ERROR SocketManager: Invalid HTTP upgrade. code=404, type=upgradeError
2020-01-23 17:59:13.456085+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736351] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: error with data: ["Invalid HTTP upgrade. code=404, type=upgradeError"]
2020-01-23 17:59:13.456546+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736351] LOG SocketManager: Starting reconnect
2020-01-23 17:59:13.456796+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736351] LOG SocketManager: Trying to reconnect
2020-01-23 17:59:13.457076+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736351] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: reconnectAttempt with data: [100]
2020-01-23 17:59:13.457298+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736351] LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
2020-01-23 17:59:13.458324+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736351] LOG SocketEngine: Engine is being released
2020-01-23 17:59:13.460873+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[34442:7736351] LOG SocketManager: Scheduling reconnect in 20.375904394158646s
```

Here is socket code:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SocketIO

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {
    static let shared = SocketIOManager()

    static let authToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authToken")
    static let bearerToken: String = "?token=Bearer " + (authToken ?? "")
    static let newBaseURL = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "baseURL")!
    //static let v = newBaseURL + "/event-stream/?token=\(bearerToken)"

    static let v = newBaseURL + "/event-stream/"

    var socket: SocketIOClient!

    // defaultNamespaceSocket and swiftSocket both share a single connection to the server
    let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: v)!, config: [.log(true), .compress, .path("?token=\(bearerToken)")])

    override init() {
        super.init()

        socket = manager.defaultSocket
    }

    func connectSocket() {
        print("manager ", manager)

        self.manager.config = SocketIOClientConfiguration(
            arrayLiteral:  .secure(true), .log(true), .forceNew(true), .reconnects(true), .reconnectAttempts(100), .forceWebsockets(true)
        )
        socket.connect()
    }

    func receiveMsg() {
        socket.on("chatevent") { (dataArray, ack) in
            print(dataArray.count)
        }
    }
}//class
```

How to connect socket and receive msg from the server?

Edited Version:

```
 import SocketIO


 class SocketIOManager: NSObject {




open class SocketConnection {

    public static let default_ = SocketConnection()
    let manager: SocketManager
    public init() {


        let authToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authToken")
        let bearerToken: String = authToken ?? ""
        let param:[String:Any] = ["token": "Bearer " + bearerToken]
        let route = "/event-stream/"

        let socketURL: URL = Utility().URLforRoute(route: route, params: param)! as URL
        manager = SocketManager(socketURL: socketURL, config: [.log(true), .compress, .forcePolling(false), .forceNew(true), .reconnects(true), .reconnectAttempts(100), .forceWebsockets(true)])
        manager.config = SocketIOClientConfiguration(arrayLiteral: .connectParams(param), .secure(true))
    }
}
 public func connectSocket(){
    let socket = SocketConnection.default_.manager.defaultSocket
    if socket.status != .connected{
        socket.connect()
    }
    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in

        print(data)
        print(ack)
        print("socket connected")
   //            self.getFinishAcknowledgement()
    }
    socket.on(clientEvent: .disconnect) {data, ack in

    }
    socket.on("unauthorized") { (data, ack) in
        print(data)
        print(ack)
        print("unauthorized user")
    }

    socket.on("chatevent") { (dataArray, ack) in

                print(dataArray.count)

            }
}
private func disconnectSocket(){
    let socket = SocketConnection.default_.manager.defaultSocket
    socket.disconnect()
}


 }


 extension NSObject {

 func URLforRoute(route: String,params:[String: Any]) -> NSURL? {



    let newBaseURL = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "baseURL")!
        //static let v = newBaseURL + "/event-stream/?token=\(bearerToken)"

    let v = newBaseURL

    if let components: NSURLComponents  = NSURLComponents(string: (v+route)){
        var queryItems = [NSURLQueryItem]()
        for(key,value) in params {
            queryItems.append(NSURLQueryItem(name:key,value: "\(value)"))
        }
        components.queryItems = queryItems as [URLQueryItem]?
        return components.url as NSURL?
    }
    return nil
}

@objc class Utility: NSObject{
       static let main = Utility()
       fileprivate override init() {}


   }


 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used pod SocketIO to connect and receive msg from server and this works fine.

Here is pod to install,

pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 15.1.0'

```
import SocketIO


class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    open class SocketConnection {

        public static let default_ = SocketConnection()
        let manager: SocketManager
        private init() {
            let param:[String:Any] = [:]
            let route = "YOUR_ROUTE"
            let socketURL: URL = Utility.URLforRoute(route: route, params: param)! as URL
            manager = SocketManager(socketURL: socketURL, config: [.log(true), .compress])
            manager.config = SocketIOClientConfiguration(arrayLiteral: .connectParams(param), .secure(true))
        }
    }
    private func connectSocket(){
        let socket = SocketConnection.default_.manager.defaultSocket
        if socket.status != .connected{
            socket.connect()
        }
        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in

            print(data)
            print(ack)
            print("socket connected")
            self.getFinishAcknowledgement()
        }
        socket.on(clientEvent: .disconnect) {data, ack in

        }
        socket.on("unauthorized") { (data, ack) in
            print(data)
            print(ack)
            print("unauthorized user")
        }
    }
    private func disconnectSocket(){
        let socket = SocketConnection.default_.manager.defaultSocket
        socket.disconnect()
    }
    private func emitLatLng(){
        let socket = SocketConnection.default_.manager.defaultSocket
        if socket.status != .connected{return}
        let params:[String:Any] = ["lat":"lat","lng":"lng","rideId":"rideId"] as Dictionary
        print(params)
        socket.emitWithAck("Acknowledgement", params).timingOut(after: 5) {data in
            print(data)
        }
    }
    private func emitEndRide(){
        let socket = SocketConnection.default_.manager.defaultSocket
        let param:[String:Any] = ["rideId":"rideId"] as Dictionary
        socket.emitWithAck("Acknowledgement", param).timingOut(after: 5) {data in
            print(data)
        }
    }
    private func getFinishAcknowledgement(){
        let socket = SocketConnection.default_.manager.defaultSocket
        socket.on("Acknowledgement") {data, ack in
            print(data)
            socket.disconnect()
        }
    }
}
```

Function for query param:

```
extension Utility{
    static func URLforRoute(route: String,params:[String: Any]) -> NSURL? {
        if let components: NSURLComponents  = NSURLComponents(string: route){
            var queryItems = [NSURLQueryItem]()
            for(key,value) in params {
                queryItems.append(NSURLQueryItem(name:key,value: "\(value)"))
            }
            components.queryItems = queryItems as [URLQueryItem]?
            return components.url as NSURL?
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

For Utility, add this:

```
@objc class Utility: NSObject{
    static let main = Utility()
    fileprivate override init() {}
}
```

Then make extension of utility and add above function "URLForRoute" in that extension.

Changes in your code:

Before

```
let authToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authToken")
let bearerToken: String = "Bearer " + (authToken ?? "")
let param:[String:Any] = ["token": bearerToken]
```

After

```
let authToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authToken")
let bearerToken: String = authToken ?? ""
let param:[String:Any] = ["Authorization": bearerToken]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206825/discussion-on-answer-by-abdul-karim-khan-socket-is-not-connected-in-ios-swift).

Comment: after adding this class how to you use it? I cannot call any functions to connect?  how do I use this class, do I create a variable manager of the class in viewdidload?

Comment: @MatthewFoster You can create an extension of your controller and inside that function you can declare above 'class' as 'open class'. Then you can use connectSocket() function in viewWillAppear() using self. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There's possible compatibility issue with server version and client version of socket io protocols, try to use the latest tag changing your Podfile like this:

```
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

target 'YourProjectName' do
    pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift.git', :tag => 'v16.0.1'
end
```