# Can I manually install Socket-IO-Client-Swift library from Xcode 11 onwards?

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io, xcode11

I don't want to use any package manager in my iOS Framework project . If there is a possibility for installing manually, will there be any issue while App Store submission?

Comment: Have a look at my answer, this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880306/socket-is-not-connected-in-ios-swift

Comment: You can install using pod.

Comment: sorry my question is not clear here I guess. Manually means I want to drag socket-io-client-swift source code files to my framework project and generate my framework with socket io as dependency. I don't want to use SPM or Cocoapods or Carthage etc..I have seen in some communities that manually importing (dragging)SocketIO framework into project is stopped, we have to use any package manager, is this true?

Comment: Sorry I haven’t used the way you are asking.